# Regex match the last part of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to add CSS reference dynamically by 'onclick' event, and filter serveral CSS references with different names but all ended with 'a', my plan is using Regex.

```
if (cssRef != /.*a.css$/){
  then add the css reference
}
```

which is not working, Thanks for your time.

Comment: functional question: what are you trying to do that makes you think you need regex here? For instance, if you're using node.js, why bother with regex when you can use `glob` patterns instead?

Comment: because it is the simplest way here?  I am just a rookie I am not aware of too many methods and not even all the pure js part. So I am sorry if I ask a wrong question.

Comment: no offense intended: it might be the right question, but we have no way of knowing, and it sounds very much like you're asking an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) question, so I want to be sure we know *what you're actually doing* that you think you need regex, in case there are better ways to do that. If you need to match files for a watch task using node.js, for instance, regex is usually not the right idea. The best answer solves your problem, not implement your solution to your problem.

Comment: Thnx, but I know nothing about node, except it is famous. I am just making a model, so with that I could apply several themes. so I want to retrieve the css reference in other html files. ya, it is weird, but the whole corp is a fake app maker, they care nothing about MVC thingy, I could not fix the whole system. Also, I do not know the principle about theme, like wordpress theme, about how do they work, what is the principle, I do not know, so I just make a model and apply css reference. but they share the a.css as common, so I need to take it out.

Comment: in that case you need to add more information. What does "The common css file name would always be a.css, could be in diff urls" mean, for instance? (there is no reason for files with the same name to *be* the same file, so how do we know it's the one? We'd have to actually check the file's content to be properly sure). Also, can you show more code to explain where `cssRef` is coming from, and how you're searching for preexisting, already loaded stylesheets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not work this way. You need to call method:

```
if (!(/.*a\.css$/).test(cssRef)) { ... }
```

Comment: careful with unescaped dot.

Answer (score 1):

You may use negative lookahead assertion.

```
if (/^(?!.*a\.css$)/.test(cssRef)) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make sure things don't have a filename `a.css`, then your current pattern is insufficient. If fact, don't use regex, just use regular string manipulation:

```
// split the HREF on slashes. If there are no slashes, this will
// be an array with just the filename in position [0].
var terms = cssRef.split('/');

// get the last element in that array, which will be the filename:
var last = terms.slice(-1)[0];

// is that filename not "a.css"? Excellent, do stuff here.
if (last.toLowerCase() !== "a.css") {
  // we know this isn't a file called a.css
}
```

No need to make things needlessly complicated by trying to force Regular Expressions into this. This way we were even able to make sure that we take weird case into account, in case one of your coworkers or whoever decides to link to it as "A.CSS" or something. Because you never know.

Comment: Thank you for your patient and instructions. This is much better. btw, can you plz tell me why regex is insufficient, or just my pattern.

Comment: the possible strings that can precede the `a.css`, especially given that what we want to achieve is one of those example cases for string.split (we just want "filename in a path"), the regex will be clunky, and consequently hard to read both for you, and for people who need to later on maintain your code. Always go with "can be understood" first, then optimize when you have to: with this code it is immediately obvious what you're doing. With a regex, it's not, and you run into issues with difference case, alternate URL patterns, etc. It's much harder to maintain.